# VBA filter on criteria and loop through rows

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am reading many workbooks, each with over 50,000 lines in them. But I only need data from certain rows. When I am in a workbook, I am trying to filter based on criteria and then loop through ONLY those rows, but it is not working.

```
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData  'Remove All Filters 
lastrow_ = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
ActiveSheet.Range("A2" & lastrow_).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=1" 'Filter on the Criteria

'Set The Range
Set rng = Range("A1:P" & Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'Loop through the range
For each row in rng
'do stuff
```

I've already defined row in another snippet of code. But this doesn't work. It doesn't loop through only the rows that apply in the filter. Any suggestions? Thank you!!!

Comment: I know it can be done by special cells. I saw another post of someone that iterated through the rows of a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Because `AutoFilter` will probably produce a discontinuous range you need to loop over `Areas` and `Ranges`, like this

```
Dim ar as Range, row As Range, rng As Range

Ws.ShowAllData  'Remove All Filters 
lastrow_ = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Ws.Range("A2" & lastrow_).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=1" 'Filter on the Criteria

'Set The Range
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:P" & Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'Loop through the range
For Each ar in rng.Areas
For Each row in ar.Rows
    'do stuff
Next row, ar
```